# WARN RESTEASY002145: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, jackson, noclassdeffounderror, jackson2

I'm struggling with below error

```
15:37:08.538 [main] - WARN RESTEASY002145: NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load builtin provider org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider from jar:file:/Users/nikulkarni/.m2/maven.repo/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider/3.0.16.Final/resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.0.16.Final.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/ProviderBase
```

I have cleaned up my pom and try to remove as much conflicts as possible, also added below dependencies, but this error remains

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-providers</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm kinda stuck on where to look further. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you verify that the dependencies are available in your target/ directory and packaged into your jar or war?

Comment: Thanks @tuberains, Those were not there in the classpath somehow, My enterprise maven repo doesn't have those versions for some reason and the proxy did not do its job, which is another problem I need to look at, however when I added those dependencies manually, this error went away. Hussh! Congrats on the first answer